# Behaviour of float left with ellipsis

Tags: html, css

I am not good in css or html and I am struggling to get something done.

The situation:

- Given that I have a parent element with variable width (for the example 30% of screen width)
- Its contents need to fill the width of that div as much as possible, but break in certain points, not on each possible word
- When the width of the div is unable to be occupied by the last in the list of children it should drop below into the next line (this behaviour is much like float:left)
- When the width is not able to be occupied by its smallest portion, that portion should text-overflow:ellipsis

**Example:**

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .container {
                width:30%;
                height:500px;
                border: 1px solid red;
            }

            .cell {
                border: 2px solid blue;
                white-space: nowrap;
                overflow: hidden;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="cell">00:20 - 10:20 text text text</div>
            <div class="cell">address of some thing text</div>
            <div class="cell">name of someone text text text</div>
            <div class="cell">some task details text text text</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When float:left is added to the .cell class, the desired behaviour that fills the width is achieved, yet it loses the overflow hidden and ellipsis overflow behaviour when you size the window down that the red border is smaller than the blue border.

Any help is welcome! Nothing is set as to the markup of the html, other than that the parent element (.container) has a variable width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Flexbox` for this approach. It is a good alternative to floats.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .container {
                width: 30%;
                height: 500px;
                border: 1px solid red;
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                align-content: flex-start;
                justify-content: flex-start;
            }

            .cell {
                border: 2px solid blue;
                white-space: nowrap;
                overflow: hidden;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="cell">00:20 - 10:20 text text text</div>
            <div class="cell">address of some thing text</div>
            <div class="cell">name of someone text text text</div>
            <div class="cell">some task details text text text</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I was looking into using flex for this but I couldn't figure out in which configuration it would work. This works! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use float, you need to add  `max-width:100%`

```css
.container {
  width: 30%;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.cell {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  
  float: left;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell">00:20 - 10:20 text text text</div>
  <div class="cell">address of some thing text</div>
  <div class="cell">name of someone text text text</div>
  <div class="cell">some task details text text text s text text text</div>
</div>
```